# Cordova long running location service

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, long-running-processes

I'm confused about when an app goes in the background and what the implications are when an app goes in the background.

I'm trying to have a long running service that detects location changes.

Plugin.xml:

```
<service android:name="MyLocationService.java" />
```

MyLocationService.java

```
public MyLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //arguments for requestUpdates defined elsewhere
        this.locationManager.requestUpdates(minTimeBetweenUpdates, minDistanceBetweenUpdates, myCriteria, this, null);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (/*rare condition*/) {
            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "We made it!");
            result.setKeepCallback(true);
            MyPlugin.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

MyPlugin.java

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    public static CallbackContext callbackContext;

    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, MyLocationService);
        MyPlugin.callbackContext = callbackContext;
        activity.startService(myIntent);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. When will the onLocationChanged stop receiving updates?
   *I know it'll stop receiving updates when I call locationManager.removeUpdates, but I wonder what other conditions will cause it to stop receiving updates...maybe when the app goes into the background?*
2. When will I not be able to invoke the javascript callback via Cordova?
3. Are there better ways to have a long running service that will "wake up the app" when necessary?